useSearchParams default value in react-router
The useSearchParams hook allows us to pass in a defaultInit parameter:
declare function useSearchParams(
  defaultInit?: URLSearchParamsInit
): [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams];

type URLSearchParamsInit =
  | string
  | ParamKeyValuePair[]
  | Record<string, string | string[]>
  | URLSearchParams;

Can anyone help me understand how this parameter should be used? When I use this parameter, my values are not added to the URL in the browser. I still need to call the setter after calling the hook in order to update the search parameters.
For example:
const myDefaults = {
    one: 'A', 
    two: 'B'
};

// Passing in myDefaults here does not affect the URL in the browser
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams(myDefaults);

// I have to additionally call useSearchParams to update the URL in the browser
useEffect(() => {
    setSearchParams(myDefaults);
}, []);

Is this expected? If so, what is the purpose of the defaultInit parameter?

defaultInit is used such that you can read from your defined default search params when it doesn't exists in the URL, it will not update the URL if it doesn't exists.
For example, if the default value for category is 1 but user opened the page without this query param: https://example.com.
In this case, you can set a default value for those query parameters such that you have a value to read from:
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams({ category: '1' });
const { category } = searchParams;

This is more or less similar to the following:
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
const { category = '1' } = searchParams;

However, do note that once you have called setSearchParams, the defaultInit will no longer take effect.
Reference: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/89049ce4ee1b265b78468f25eb494eef240a7e40/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L1453-L1455

Edit: If you want to auto update the search params if it doesn't exists, you can write a utility function like this (not tested):
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { createSearchParams, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function useSearchParamsWithUpdate(defaultInit) {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams(defaultInit);
  const defaultSearchParams = useRef(createSearchParams(defaultInit));

  useEffect(() => {
    const update = {};
    let needUpdate = false;

    defaultSearchParams.current.forEach((v, k) => {
      if (!searchParams.has(k)) {
        update[k] = v;
        needUpdate = true;
      }
    });

    if (needUpdate) setSearchParams(update, { replace: true });
  }, [searchParams, setSearchParams]);

  return [searchParams, setSearchParams];
}


Thanks. So it's expected that defaultInit doesnt update the browser URL? I guess I was expecting react-router to handle applying defaults and merge them with whatever is already in the URL, but perhaps that's up to the developer to do and then call the setter.

@devklick Yes, I have modified my answer above to include a sample code that should does what you want.
